# bootstrap 3 grid with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's an input type number that dynamically sets the number of spaces to be left for a fill in the blanks exam controller:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Número de Espacios</label>
    <input type="number" min="2" ng-model="options" />
</md-input-container>
```

The idea of this fill in the blanks controller is to look something like this:

A-_______________________________________ B-___________________________________

C-_______________________________________ D-___________________________________

Is there an automated way to print this grid? This is what I have so far in terms of code:

```
<div ng-show="!optionsBig">
        <div ng-repeat="opt in NumberOfOptions track by $index">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="question-line-row">
                        <span>{{alphabet($index) + '-'}}</span>
                        <hr class="question-line" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is what is rendered:

[image: ng-repeat bootstrap 3 grid]

Is there a way to properly reproduce what I'm trying to achieve? Some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, your ng-repeat statement is repeating a new bootstrap row every time. The following code should work for you:

```
<div ng-show="!optionsBig">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="opt in NumberOfOptions track by $index">
            <div class="question-line-row">
                <span>{{alphabet($index) + '-'}}</span>
                <hr class="question-line" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will repeat each column rather than each row. Remember, ng-repeat repeats the element that is marked with it plus all of its children.
Also be aware that bootstrap starts to misbehave when you have many columns in a row element. I have done it but you may start to see unexpected results once you add more and more.

Comment: worked like a charm, just added some extra code to prevent weird things from happening, all in all ,thanks!

Comment: great, glad I could help!